# Ошибка при анализе значения «margin». Потерянное объявление.

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток.
У меня вот образовалась такая ошибка, при отладке выводит такое сообщение. Не могу понять, как его исправить. Сам я новичок, вот и не понимаю, как решить данную проблему.

> Ошибка при анализе значения «margin». Потерянное объявление.
> Пустая строка не может быть аргументом метода getElementById().

Указывает на

```
     $(this).animate({margin:'0 0 0 20px'},
                {duration:200});
```

Проблема в том, что в IE7 не отображается, а мне очень нужно, чтобы работало. Помогите разобрать ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-моему, описание ошибки достаточно понятно. В ней не может быть тега `<br/>`. синтаксис `animate()` содержит только конечные значения, скорость перехода и функция обратного вызова. То есть удалите этот тег из объявления метода `animante()`. Если принципиально нужно вставить `<br/>`, тогда можно использовать нечто подобное:

```
$(this).append('<br\/>');
```

Comment: ЛОЛ а помоему <br> это проблема того что автор еще не знаком с тем как тут правильно оформлять код, не? xDDD

Comment: <br> эт я добавил чтобы перейи на новую строкку думал что на странице будет отображаться в одной линии.

Answer (score 2):

Ты можешь работать отдельно с каждым отступом?
вот так, например работает

```
$(this).animate({marginLeft:'20px'},{duration:200});
```

Comment: ах да, если бы автор понимал примерно как работает .animate() то такого вопроса не возникало бы...<br>
<b>Андрей Суржиков</b> вы абсолютно правы, если необходимо сделать именно так то надо использовать `marginLeft, marginRight, marginTop и marginBottom`...